# angular - url history is lost/browser forward button is disabled when router.navigate changes the url

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

URL history is lost (browser forward button is disabled) when when router.navigate changes the url. Child component is loaded via router-outlet.

Without query-parameter in the parent URL, browser retains history.
Example : https://website.com -> https://website.com/123456(child) -> https://website.com - **maintains history.**

But when we update URL with query-parameter then we are losing the history of navigated to child component.

Can you please suggest solution for this issue ? Thanks in advance.

I tried to apply ExtraOptions (https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions), but it did not worked.